# How to clear error message?

Tags: javascript

I was trying to display an "error message" in DIFFERENT color using CSS when the user inputs letter instead of a number in a form and I did. The problem is that the error message is still there when the user corrects the error and writes a number. How do I fix that?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    #error {color: red;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="error"></p>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <input id="demo1" type="text" />
    <button onclick="vote()"> Click here</button>
    <script>
      function vote() {
        var age = document.getElementById("demo1").value;
        if (isNaN(age)) {
          document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Input Error!!";
        } else {
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (age < 18) ? "Too young to vote" : "Old enough to vote";
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your `else` clause, change the `innerHTML` of `error` just like when you're setting the error message. Just set it to an empty string: `""`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added `document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = "";` to clean up before to process a new entry:

```js
function vote() {

  var aaa = document.getElementById("error");
  var bbb = document.getElementById("demo");
  
aaa.innerHTML = "";
bbb.innerHTML = "";  
  
  var age = document.getElementById("demo1").value;
  if (isNaN(age)) {
    aaa.innerHTML = "Input Error!!";
  } else {
    bbb.innerHTML = (age < 18) ? "Too young to vote" : "Old enough to vote";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background: lavender;  
}

#error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input id="demo1" type="text" />
<button onclick="vote()"> Click here</button>
<p id="error"></p><p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could add a keyup event on the input so it would check every character

```
<input id="demo1" type="text" onkeyup="validate()" />

function validate() {
    if (isNaN(age)) {
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Input Error!!";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "";
    }
}
```